# MySQL Error - SQLSTATE [42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: mysql, pdo, fuelphp

I've looked through the suggested code and cannot find an answer that fixes the problem so I am asking away.

I am using MAMP v2.0.5, MySQL v5.5.9, PHP v5.3.6 (according to MAMP, v5.3.8 according to OS X) and FuelPHP v1.1, and being new to frameworks I am working through a tutorial. Part of the tutorial requires the use of 'oil' to carry out migrations to update the project. Having defined a table, the migration applies the SQL to generate the table. When I do so, I get the above error. Having looked through the generated code I can't find any errors (maybe I am missing something obvious). I am using PDO and have also checked that my `sql_mode = ''`, which it does. Running a MySQL query from the command line and phpMyAdmin confirms this. I think this is a MySQL error and not a problem with FuelPHP/oil. Does anybody have any suggestions?

The generated SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` varhcar(50) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `group` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `last_login` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `login_hash` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `profile_fields` text NOT NULL,
    `created_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `updated_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY `id` (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

The error:

```
    bash:blog me$ oil refine migrate
Error - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varhcar(50) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `group` int(11) NOT NU' at line 3 with query: "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` varhcar(50) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `group` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `last_login` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `login_hash` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `profile_fields` text NOT NULL,
    `created_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `updated_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY `id` (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;" in COREPATH/classes/database/pdo/connection.php on line 137
```

Comment: Although I have just noticed that "group" is a reserved word, having changed this to "user_group" I still get the same error.

Comment: There's also a point that doesn't need fixing as MySQL "auto-corrects" it. `PRIMARY KEY id (id)` is really the same as `PRIMARY KEY (id)`. You can't select a name for the Primary Key. It's called `PRIMARY`, by default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You made a typo:

```
`username` varhcar(50) NOT NULL,
```

should be:

```
`username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: Thanks. Boy do I feel like a plonker, I've been looking at that for hours!

Comment: When mysql gives the error *.... for the right syntax to use near '_<string>_' *, just check your query in the part immediately preceding _<string>_, or the first characters in _<string>_. Error log is there to help you

Comment: Thanks. I'm particularly bad when it comes to understanding the errors. Your help, albeit very easy to spot, was greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?

Comment: @Wesley Murch Sure, did that.

Comment: whats the difference between them ?