# My databases are not visible on phpMyAdmin but available in the data folder in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have several databases in my localhost. Recently, I noticed that the root user didn't have a password yet I had set it before and used to be working. On opening the `phpMyAdmin`, I got access denied but after changing the settings to remove the password, I was able to access it. However, I now realize that all my databases are not available apart from the default `xampp` databases yet when I check from `C:\xampp\mysql\data` folder, all the database folders are there together with data. When I try to create a database that I know exists, it is created without popping any duplicate error. What could be happening with my localhost server?

**UPDATE**

I found out where the problem is and why the databases are not visible. First, the file location changed from `C:\xampp\mysql\data` to `C:MySql5\Data`. I guess there must have been an update without my knowledge. I have however tried to copy one of the database files to the new file location but I am getting an error of `table.menu doesn't exist` for a table that I want to view its properties. Could this be a new change to the MySQL? I have checked `MySQL version` that I am running is `5.5.15`

Comment: check do you have any other user accounts exists with this query `SELECT User FROM mysql.user;`

Comment: These are the listed users: `root`, `root`, `japheth`, `root`. I tried to login with `japheth` but still the same results. The other root users I am assuming they have the same priviledges.

Comment: For the other `root` users, I have checked in the database and their hosts are: `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and `::1`

Comment: can you login via root?  if yes, create another use with all privileges and use that to view databases

Comment: Thanks @DanyalSandeelo, I have done that but there is no any change. No databases are displayed.

Comment: @DhanuK kindly check an update that I have made to the question.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo kindly check an update that I have made to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
grant all on *.* to root@'localhost';
flush privileges;
```

and this too

```
grant all on *.* to root@'127.0.0.1';
flush privileges;
```

The query will assign all privileges to root user on all databases. You would be able to view databases then.

Comment: I have tried this but still nothing shows. I am using HeidiSQL to login but no databases are displayed.

Comment: you cannot connect with Heidi using `root` in order to connect via Heidi, you root needs to have an access from `%`

try this

`create user test@'%' identified by 'your_pass';`
and then run the above given queries against your test user and then login via heidi

Comment: I have created the user test using your command. However, when I try to run the above given queries against the user test I get the error `ERROR 1133 (42000): Can't find any matching row in the user table`.

Comment: are you sure about the syntax? and how did you create test user? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474576/mysql-error-sqlstate-42000-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1064

Comment: I have noticed one problem, the current setup uses the following folder `C:\MySql5` that is not in the `xampp` folder. I think this is where the problem is.